# Do you use 个 when describing distances/weights？

Tags: measure-word

I'm trying to figure out if you ever use 个 when describing distances or weight. For example, people say "十公里“ NOT "十个公里“ － right？ does the same apply for weights? like 公斤？

Answer (score 1):

No, in general, you shall not use 个 before a unit, no matter what the unit is used for (mass, length,area etc ). 个 is a counter/measure word in Chinese, one of whose functions is to count something, like a unit, so you don't need to put a unit before a unit.
In some weird scenarios, you may use 个 before a unit.for example,

> 本文中有几**个公斤**？ How many occurrences of "kilogram" in the article ?

Here, kilogram itself is treated as a common word instead of a unit.

Comment: Good explanation, but the example sounds artificial - in real life scenario it would be phrased differently to avoid any possible ambiguity, e.g. `本文中公斤一词出现了几次`.

Comment: @ns.x Yes, it's constructed by me on purpose. That's why I say "weird".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in some special cases.

Formally, the construction should be `numeral + quantifier + noun`, such as:

```
你今天打算跑几公里路？
我打算跑5公里路。
```

If `路` can be deduced from the context, it could be omitted:

```
你今天打算跑几公里？
我打算跑5公里。
```

And in spoken language, it could be transformed to an "odd" construction of `numeral + quantifier + noun` further, in which `公里` is regarded as a noun.

```
你今天打算跑几个公里？
我打算跑5个公里。
```

Here's another example:

```
你家卧室有几个平方？
也就10个平方吧。
```

Anyway, this usage is very limited, for example, you can use it for the quantifier `斤`, it's unnatural.

```
鸡蛋你打算买几个斤？
买5个斤。
```

Comment: No. In Chinese we use quantifiers only before objects.  And units can be used as quantifier. 几个公里 is ridiculous, which I never saw anyone use. But as to 一个平方, it's an exception. So is 一个立方. I don't suggest using these exceptions, which probably confuse Chinese learners.

Comment: @SeanC. I can't summarize the grammar explicitly and clearly even though I'm a native Chinese, all I can say is these exceptions exist in the Chinese, especially in spoken language. I know it probably confuse Chinese learners, I just want they know it is used by Chinese, and when they hear them somewhere they won't be confused.

Comment: @SeanC. BTW, you can find many samples of `几个公里` at Baidu. http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%22%E5%87%A0%E4%B8%AA%E5%85%AC%E9%87%8C%22&tn=baidu&ie=utf-8&f=3&rsv_bp=1&inputT=2859&rsv_sug3=14&rsv_sug4=218&rsv_sug1=5&rsv_sug2=0&rsp=0&rsv_sug=2&bs=%E5%87%A0%E4%B8%AA%E5%85%AC%E9%87%8C&rsv_spt=3

Comment: Usually we say "你今天打算跑多少公里？"